# Need help creating basic baseball bases figure

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an indicator for which bases have a person on them. I'm using bootstrap react's Container, Row, and Col for positioning and created my own CSS classes for the triangles. But the problem I'm running into is I don't know how to get them to touch each other to make a diamond for the base's shape. I'm also open to any other ways of doing this.

**Current Output**

[image]

**Desired Output**

[image]

**My Components Container**

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col sm="auto">
        <div className="triangle-blank"></div>
        <div className="triangle-left"></div>
    </Col>
    <Col sm="auto">
        <div className="triangle-left"></div>
        <div className="triangle-right"></div>
    </Col>
    <Col sm="auto">
        <div className="triangle-right"></div>
        <div className="triangle-left"></div>
    </Col>
    <Col sm="auto">
        <div className="triangle-blank"></div>
        <div className="triangle-right"></div>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

**My CSS classes**

```
.triangle-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.triangle-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #555;
}

.triangle-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid #555;
}

.triangle-blank {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

[**CodeSandbox Link**](https://codesandbox.io/s/baseball-component-help-stackoverflow-forked-s5zfi?file=/example.js)

Comment: Please may you edit the question with a [mcve]? the current example doesn't give enough information as to why you're getting that output

Comment: What else could I add. I gave the code that is needed for the figure. There's nothing else besides the boilerplate react component layout and import {Container, Row, Col) from "react-bootstrap; I stated all of this in the description You want me to give you the basic react broiler plate that is needed to render the page?

Comment: An example which uses bootstrap and let's us run it so we can see the output ourselves without an image?

Comment: Just added a CodeSandbox link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct solution that uses react-bootstrap and custom CSS

**In my render() of React Component**

```
const styles = {
    grid: {
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 0,
    },
    row: {
        marginLeft: 3,
        marginRight: 0,
    },
    col: {
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 0,
    },
    center: {
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 0,
    },
};

<Container style={styles.grid}>
    <Row style={styles.row}>
        <Col sm="auto" style={styles.col}>
            <div className="diamond second-base active"></div>
        </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row style={styles.col}>
        <Col sm="auto" style={styles.center}>
            <div className="diamond third-base"></div>
        </Col>
        <Col sm="auto" style={styles.col}>
            <div className="diamond first-base"></div>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Container>
```

**CSS Classes**

```
div.diamond.second-base {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #CBCCCE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  color: #6C6D6F;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant-caps: inherit;
  font-variant-east-asian: inherit;
  font-variant-ligatures: inherit;
  font-variant-numeric: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  height: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.second-base:after {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid #CBCCCE;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.second-base.active {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #0066CC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  color: #6C6D6F;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant-caps: inherit;
  font-variant-east-asian: inherit;
  font-variant-ligatures: inherit;
  font-variant-numeric: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  height: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.second-base.active:after {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid #0066CC;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.third-base {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #CBCCCE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #6C6D6F;
  float: left;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant-caps: inherit;
  font-variant-east-asian: inherit;
  font-variant-ligatures: inherit;
  font-variant-numeric: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  height: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.third-base:after {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid #CBCCCE;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.third-base.active {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #0066CC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #6C6D6F;
  float: left;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant-caps: inherit;
  font-variant-east-asian: inherit;
  font-variant-ligatures: inherit;
  font-variant-numeric: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  height: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.third-base.active:after {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid #0066CC;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.first-base {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #CBCCCE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #6C6D6F;
  float: right;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant-caps: inherit;
  font-variant-east-asian: inherit;
  font-variant-ligatures: inherit;
  font-variant-numeric: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  height: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.first-base:after {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid #CBCCCE;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.first-base.active {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #0066CC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #6C6D6F;
  float: right;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant-caps: inherit;
  font-variant-east-asian: inherit;
  font-variant-ligatures: inherit;
  font-variant-numeric: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  height: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 0;
}

div.diamond.first-base.active:after {
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid #0066CC;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  width: 0;
}
```

**Solution link:** [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/baseball-bases-component-forked-113u7?file=/example.js)

Answer (score 1):

Will SVG work?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0  640 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <rect id="svgEditorBackground" x="0" y="0" width="640" height="200" style="fill: none; stroke: none;" />
   <g id="e4__group">
      <path d="M-35.815383,-37.476921l-4,4l4,4l4,-4Z" style="fill:white; stroke:black; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;stroke-width:1px;" id="e1_shape" transform="matrix(8.13356 0 0 8.13356 372.893 316.834)" />
      <path d="M-40.492315,-32.676928l-4,4l4,4l4,-4Z" style="fill:white; stroke:black; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;stroke-width:1px;" id="e4_shape" transform="matrix(8.13356 0 0 8.13356 372.893 316.834)" />
      <path d="M-31.138467,-32.800005l-4,4l4,4l4,-4Z" style="fill:white; stroke:black; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;stroke-width:1px;" id="e2_shape" transform="matrix(8.13356 0 0 8.13356 372.893 316.834)" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with <svg/>. I need to be able to highlight the bases when a player is on it too.

Comment: That's a separate question but it can be done.